# Game object not showing when using "Material Color.Lerp"

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm using a coroutine to make an object pulsate. Coroutine works if applied to materials that use the default shader. Unfortunately I also have to apply a fading effect but the fading effect doesn't work on the default shader. I then created one that works for fading, it also corrects an "error" (two sided facing) but can't make my object pulsate. How can i modify my shader to have all that i need? I'll post the code of the shader and of the coroutine below

Shader

```c#
Shader "Custom/Standard Two Sided Soft Blend" {
    Properties {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        [NoScaleOffset] _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        [Toggle] _UseMetallicMap ("Use Metallic Map", Float) = 0.0
        [NoScaleOffset] _MetallicGlossMap("Metallic", 2D) = "black" {}
        [Gamma] _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
        _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
        _BumpScale("Scale", Float) = 1.0
        [NoScaleOffset] _BumpMap("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
        _Cutoff("Alpha Cutoff", Range(0.01,1)) = 0.5
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent"  "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="fade" }
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        LOD 200
        ZWrite Off
        Cull Off

        Pass {
            ColorMask 0
            ZWrite On

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed _Cutoff;

            v2f vert (appdata_img v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                clip(col.a - _Cutoff);
                return 0;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        Pass
        {
            Tags {"LightMode"="ShadowCaster"}
            ZWrite On
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct v2f {
                V2F_SHADOW_CASTER;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER_NORMALOFFSET(o)
                o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
                return o;
            }

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            fixed _Cutoff;

            float4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                clip(col.a - _Cutoff);
                SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
            }
            ENDCG
        }

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows alpha:fade nolightmap
        #pragma shader_feature _USEMETALLICMAP_ON
        #pragma target 3.0

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        sampler2D _MetallicGlossMap;
        sampler2D _BumpMap;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            fixed facing : VFACE;
        };

        half _Glossiness;
        half _Metallic;
        fixed4 _Color;
        half _BumpScale;
        fixed _Cutoff;

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
            // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
            fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
            o.Albedo = c.rgb;

            #ifdef _USEMETALLICMAP_ON
            fixed4 mg = tex2D(_MetallicGlossMap, IN.uv_MainTex);
            o.Metallic = mg.r;
            o.Smoothness = mg.a;
            #else
            o.Metallic = _Metallic;
            o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
            #endif

            // Rescales the alpha on the blended pass
            o.Alpha = saturate(c.a / _Cutoff);

            o.Normal = UnpackScaleNormal(tex2D(_BumpMap, IN.uv_MainTex), _BumpScale);

            if (IN.facing < 0.5)
                o.Normal *= -1.0;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Coroutine

```c#
public IEnumerator PulsatingCoroutine(string objName,Color start,Color end)
{
    corout = true;
    float i = 0;
    float rate = 0.3f;
    while (isRunningPulse)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime*rate;
        GameObject pulsatingGameobject = GameObject.Find(objName);
        lastGo = pulsatingGameobject;
        float t = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time - startTime) * speed);
        pulsatingGameobject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp (start, end, Mathf.PingPong(i * 2, 1) );
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is ti not showing at all or only once you started your Coroutine? And what values exactly do you pass in as `start` and `end`? Btw you should strongly avoid using `Find` and `GetComponent` each frame within the `while` loop. If possible move this line up before the `while` so it is only done once!

Comment: Oh GOd, it was a color problem... Gave the wrong value to alpha... Ty derHugo

Comment: no problem ;) just made the same experiences .. and just learned that `Mathf.PingPong` exists .. that's why StackOverflow is so cool